# JSON use inside WSO2 ESB store and forward mecanism

Tags: arrays, json, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a problem with JSON use inside WSO2 ESB 4.9.1. I use 
Builder org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder
Formatter org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter in axis2.xml

I use a Message Store and Message Processor with ApacheMQ to do a store and forward. Every thing works well except when the input JSON contains an array with only one element in this case when the processor send the JSON to the endpoint It has converted it on a simple object.

for example I put in entry { "a":"test", "tab":[ {id:1}] }

but a the end of store and forward I have { "a":"test", "tab":{id:1} }

Have you got an idea of the right parameters I should use to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, and will be fixed in a future release. This is not something related to store and forward. You may be able to reproduce the same issue just by using an API or a Proxy service even.

Thanks & Regards,
Ravindra.